# Manifest merger failed when I add third party library

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am getting these errors when build starts.

```
 Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library 
  [com.github.ChiliLabs:ChiliPhotoPicker:0.3.1] C:\Users\DELL\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files- 
 **strong text** 2.1\b034ff3194e7ba4b9353c2b9bbcaf626\ChiliPhotoPicker-0.3.1\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be 
  using APIs not available in 19
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 19,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="lv.chi.photopicker" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

Comment: The error seems to tell you want to do (see the "Suggestion" part). Beyond that, what is your question?

Answer (score -1):

Increase your `minSdkVersion` from 19 to 21 in your `build.gradle` file in `app` module.